# Should I accept these kind of edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I was in the suggested-edits queue and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13262972) edit suggestion.

It actively changes the code, the codes style, and the content of the answer.

However, it is IMO an improvement **IF** the code is correct.

Should I just skip the suggested edit and let others verify the code, or is it to be rejected and should be a new answer?

Comment: I hate it when people use a reject reason like `Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.` for cases like this.  That's *obviously* not true, and is a really rude response to someone who's obviously trying to be helpful but just made the wrong decision about where to put their contribution (as an edit instead of a new answer + comment).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, it was "attempt to reply", not "no improvement whatsoever". I've long been in favor of replacing the text for the "no improvement whatsoever" reject reason with something more tactful. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242160/168333) is the rationale behind the current text.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: The reject message is fine; it accurately describes the criteria when it should be used.  The problem is with jerks who use this reason when it doesn't apply.  Maybe we can audit / police inappropriate use of this reject reason, and/or add another one for edits with a mix of good and bad, or cases like this where they're (maybe) good but too intrusive.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd like one for mixed cases, but the wording is going to be tricky. I often use a custom reason ("while some of this edit is good, ..."). I don't think the mods are too keen on flags saying "rejected for the wrong reason".

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Agreed, not flag-worthy.  But there are review audits and stuff, and using this reason inappropriately should be a reason to fail.  (I don't actually do a lot of review myself.  I feel like my time is much better spent taking care of the side by dealing with low quality assembly/x86 questions with edits / comments / votes, rather than reviewing changes to questions about things I don't know / use / am not interested in.)  But yeah, obviously a custom reason is most appropriate.  There should be more pressure on reviewers to type something for cases where none of the canned ones fit

Comment: I would've chosen "Conflicts with author's intent" as a reject reason. It clearly isn't any kind of attempt to respond to anyone; it just changes too much of the post. It may or may not actually change things that the original author intended, though; we don't know without a lot of analysis and asking the original author.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This type of edit should usually be rejected.

It is an upvoted, accepted answer, meaning that the OP and others have vouched for the code *before* it was edited. Changing it this much puts words in the OP's mouth.

The only case when you should accept such edits, is if you are **absolutely** certain that it fixes a problem with the answer. Usually, if this is necessary, it will already be discussed in the comments.

The editor did better to comment, if they believed the answer was wrong or needed improvement. Or write their own answer.

When in doubt, <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Comment: In this case, it does appear that the code is an improvement at first glance. I would encourage the editor to post a separate answer with appropriate credit (that it's a revised version) and a description of what functional changes/improvements have been made, so it can be voted on separately. If the editor doesn't wish to gain reputation from the answer, they can mark it as a Community Wiki.